# How exactly do the Early Bird/Night Owl Town Ordinances work?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

According to [this site](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Ordinance) the key benefits of either the Early Bird/Night Owl town ordinance are:

- The villagers of the town change their schedule to fit the new time
- The villagers wake up and the shops open a varying number of hours earlier/later

But do they **shift** the opening hours or **extend** them to either 3 hours earlier/later?

E.g. if I choose the Night Owl ordinance, will the shops still open in the morning at the regular time? I cannot check right now because I'm not that far into the game and the information I find is kind of vague.

Comment: I asked this the other day. Has all the shop times http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/when-are-all-the-stores-open-with-and-without-ordinances/121867#121867

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Early Bird and Night Owl extend the hours, not shift them. So using the Early Bird ordinance will result in all shops opening 3-4 hours earlier ([depends on the shop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121865/when-are-all-the-stores-open-with-and-without-ordinances/121867#121867)) and closing at the regular time. The night Owl ordinance will result in all shops open at regular time, and closing 3-4 hours later.