# When are all the stores open (with and without ordinances)?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've checked several wiki's and none of them seem to agree on what the hours of operation are for the stores in the game. Here is what I have so far and I am just curious if anybody can fill in the missing information? I just don't have most of the shops yet and I acan only confirm the Night Owl Ordinance of The Able Sister, Nook Homes, the Garden Center and Nookling Junction.

I am pretty sure of anything not marked but feel free to double check. I'm actually really surprised how hard it was to find what I did.

(I checked [Animal Crossing Wikia](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Crossing_Wiki), [acwiki3ds](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/), [Nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Main_Page), [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf), [BidoofCrossing](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/) (the only one to have any hours for Kicks or Shampoodle), and [Thonky](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/).)

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing this information with us!  One problem though... this doesn't really fit Stack Exchange's Q&A format as it currently exists.  You can easily edit it to do so by simply copying all of the times the shops are open into an answer to this question, and then editing that answer as you confirm times.  Thanks again!

Comment: hehe I was thinking of doing that if I was able to find all of them. Since I was missing and unsure of technically most I figured it still qualified as a proper question.

Comment: Looks good!  And yeah, I think it's a great question.  Might even be a good candidate for Community Wiki, if there's enough collaboration necessary for a complete answer.  See more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Club LOL **12pm to 8pm** (No Party) **8pm to 2am** (Party)

### Open 24/7

- Museum
- Post Office
- Mayor's Office
- Dream Suite
- Photo Booth
- Police Station
- The Roost Cafe
- Reset Surveillance Center
- Happy Home Showcase

### Without Ordinance

- Re-Tail **9am to 11pm**
- Nook's Homes **10am to 8pm**
- Nookling Junction **8am to 10pm**
- T&T Mart **7am to 12am**
- Super T&T **9am to 8pm**
- T.I.Y **10am to 11pm**
- T&T Emporium **9am to 9pm**
- Able Sisters **10am to 9pm**
- Garden Center **9am to 8pm**
- Kicks **10am to 8pm**
- Shampoodle **10am to 10pm**
- Fortune Teller's shop **9am to 7pm** (One day a week)
- Crazy Redd's 10am to 11pm (Need Confirmation) (One Day a Week)

### With Early Bird Ordinance

- Re-Tail **6am to 11pm**
- Nook's Homes **6am to 8pm**
- Nookling Junction **6am to 10pm**
- T&T Mart **6am to 12am**
- Super T&T **6am to 8pm**
- T.I.Y **6am to 11pm**
- T&T Emporium **6am to 9pm**
- Able Sisters **7am to 9pm**
- Garden Center **7am to 8pm**
- Kicks **7am to 8pm**
- Shampoodle **7am to 8pm**
- Fortune Teller's shop **6am to 7pm** (One day a Week)
- Crazy Redd's ???   (One Day a Week)

### With Night Owl Ordinance

- Re-Tail **9am to 2am**
- Nook's Homes **10am to 12am**
- Nookling Junction **8am to 12am**
- T&T Mart **7am to 5am**
- Super T&T **9am to 12am**
- T.I.Y **10am to 3am**
- T&T Emporium **9am to 12am**
- Able Sisters **10am to 12am**
- Garden Center **9am to 11pm**
- Kicks **10am to 11pm**
- Shampoodle **10am to 11pm**
- Fortune Teller's shop **9am to 11pm** (One Day a Week)
- Crazy Redd's **10pm-2am**    (One Day a Week)

Comment: The Prima guide says Club LOL's hours should be 12pm-2am (Default); 10am-2am (Early Riser); 12pm-5am (Night owl), with no mention of parties.  Not sure if this is correct, since I've had guides be wrong before, and I don't have the club myself as yet.

Comment: I have no idea. I don't have it yet. Do you know if The Fortune Teller and Crazy Redd always come the same day of the week for all players or if it is on a per town basis?

Comment: I think in Redd's case at least it's just a random day each week, varying between weeks - I'm pretty sure I had him twice in about three days, once on a Saturday and then on the Monday or Tuesday following...  Haven't seen the fortune seller yet to know about that.

Comment: When is the closing time on Saturdays? I went to my club at 1:30am on Saturday (default ordinances), but it still said closed. :(

Answer (score -1):

I got this information from setting my clock to 4am and running around writing down the times I have the bell ordinance in effect that should mean i have default for all my shop times.

- **re-tail 9am-11pm**
- **Nook's homes 10am-8pm**
- **T&T mart 7am-12am**
- **gardening 9am-8pm**
- **Shampoodle 10am-8pm**
- **Able sisters 10am-9pm**
- **kicks 10am-8pm**

lol 12pm-2am
 *(for these times i stood outside the club at 11:59am and clicked the door couldnt get in when the clock hit 12 i went inside for the closing i stood outside until the sign turned off at 2am)*